# How to calculate the angle of a triangle with Compass/Sass?

Tags: sass, geometry, compass-sass, angle

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to use the compass math helper functions.

Assume I have a triangle ABC with C = 90 degrees. I would like to know how many degrees A is.

The formula for that is easy: `A = arctan(a/b)`, but how do I code that with Compass and Sass?

Comment: What do you mean "How do I code that", what have you tried? What do you intend to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a function in Ruby to do this.  Since you're already using Compass, you can take advantage of the [Sassy Math](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Sassy-math) extension.  Their Ruby code for this function looks like this (hope I've got the right one here):

```
  def atan2(y, x)
    y = y.value.to_f
    x = x.value.to_f
    result = Math.atan2(y, x)
    Sass::Script::Number.new(result)
  end
```